# FusionChart hide lines

Tags: javascript, show-hide, fusioncharts

I'm using `FusionCharts 3.3.1` (JS renderer) and I want to add two buttons "Hide All" and "Show All". I couldn't find it in the API for set visible of data series, and only one solution I figured was to generate new JSON for chart with setted "visible" option inside and redraw it again. Is there a better solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, with the current version of FusionCharts V3.3.1, this is the the most appropriate solution to show/hide all the data plots at a time.